# Solspace Calendar - Display next 4 events in order of occurence (date/time)

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar, orderby, sort

I am replacing an existing channel:entries tag pair which was displaying upcoming events, to now use the Solspace Calendar plugin (previous post [here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/41216/ordering-sorting-channel-entries-by-calendar-date))

All I want to do is display the next 4 upcoming events.

(In order of occurrence - date/time.)
(Any event that has a category checkbox selected will not display.)
(The second/fourth div has a different style class)

```
{exp:calendar:events channel="event" category="not 15" sort="asc" date_range_end="12 months"}
        <div class="hevent">
            <div class="{switch='hedate1|hedate2'}">
                <div class="day">{calendar:event_start_date format="%l"}</div>
                <div class="date">{calendar:event_start_date format="%j"}</div>
                <div class="month">{calendar:event_start_date format="%M %Y"}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="hecont">
                <h4>{calendar:title}</h4>
                <p>{calendar:e_summary}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="hecont">
                <p><i>{calendar:event_start_date_timestamp_utc format="%g:%i%a"} to {calendar:event_end_date_timestamp_utc format="%g:%i%a"}</i>
                <br>{calendar:e_location}</p>
            </div>
        <a href="events/whats-happening#{url_title}" title="{title}"></a>
        </div>
{exp:calendar:events}
```

Using Calendar 2.3.2

It appears that 'event_limit' no longer works?
Also unless I add "date_range_end="12 months", then NO results appear, even though the docs note that "If this parameter is not specified, then the default limit of 12 results will kick in".

What am I missing? ANY HELP is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you're viewing Calendar 1.x docs or sources, as the info you mention appears outdated. Have a look at the [date_range_end](http://docs.solspace.com/expressionengine/calendar/v2/templating/events.html#date-range-end) parameter (default value is `today`, which is why you need to specify something like 12 months in a scenario like this).

As for limiting, use the [limit](http://docs.solspace.com/expressionengine/calendar/v2/templating/events.html#limit) parameter (`limit="4"`), as `event_limit` is from Calendar 1.x as well.

Comment: Thanks. When I searched the docs I getting redirected to content from the wrong version. I was also using/testing a field checkbox conditional (instead of the category checkbox) which was causing strange results but have fixed that now. Cheers.